# How does General Hux find Kylo Ren in time?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

Shortly before Starkiller base explodes, Supreme Leader Snoke tells General Hux to retrieve Kylo Ren. Kylo Ren was on the ground dying in the middle of a forest. (Movie logic says that he found Ren, so we could have a sequel.)

### How did General Hux find him in time?

Comment: The other question is asking whether Kylo Ren survived. I was more of assuming that Hux got Kylo Ren off-planet and just asking how he did so. I don't think that it's a dupe.

Comment: The "homing beacon in Kylo Ren's belt" part is in the related Q's answer. Maybe not a dupe but related for sure. :)

Comment: It's all done with mirrors or maybe it's just a movie so we should really all relax (to paraphrase Joel Hodgson and Josh Weinstein).

Comment: If you've only seen the movie and nothing else, technically you don't even know _if_ Hux found Kylo in time. Anything else would be a spoiler!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Hux followed a signal from a position sensor embedded in Kylo Ren's belt to find him, just in the nick of time.

According to the official Alan Dean Foster novelization, Hux takes a team of stormtroopers in a shuttle to Kylo's position, which he could triangulate from a position sensor that is apparently part of Kylo's belt:

> A deep gully formed, separating her [Rey] from General Hux and the arriving troopers.  **Utilizing the tiny position sensor emplaced in Ren's belt, Hux had tracked him to this spot.**
>
> (*Chapter XVIII*)

They carry Kylo into the shuttle, and off they go to safety.

This scene does not actually appear in the film.

According to the novelization, the rescue of Kylo Ren happens just before Chewie rescues Rey and Finn, and Finn had watched from across the crater as Hux's stormtroopers collected Ren — which means that Rey knows that Kylo survived (assuming his injuries weren't fatal).

Comment: It would be cool if Kylo Ren somehow actually died.

Comment: @corsiKa hahaha! very acurate assesment of his skils.

Comment: @corsiKa You mean, he just had a run of bad luck? Naah, he had bad stats to begin with. Not enough XP.

Comment: @ibid opening crawl: "Star Wars episode VIII. The galaxy is at peace, after Kylo Ren's death from septicaemia and General Hux's decision to retire and take up gardening. However, all is not well. Chewbacca has moved in with Rey and Finn, and there are hairs *everywhere*. Can their fledgling relationship take this strain? And who is this oddly familiar, tall, gaunt, grey-skinned stranger who has just bought the apartment next door?"

Comment: @user568458 Nooooooooooooooo!!!

Comment: Wow. I didn't know that...

Comment: @user568458: Your crawl isn't ending with a phrase that is hookable by a scene starting the movie. also your crawl isn't ending on ". ..."'s ^^

Comment: @Zaibis It also lacks UPPER CASE.

Comment: My first thought reading the question was "Given Kylo Ren's emotional instability, Snoke probably put a tracking device on him to keep tabs on his whereabouts."

Comment: I suppose the next question is then how Finn watched the Stormtroopers and Hux collect Ren when he was busting lying unconscious in a pile of snow…